# Copy and Paste charts to slide in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm creating a VBA code to copy a chart of a specific worksheet of Excel Workbook and paste it into a Power Point slide. Here's my code:

I'm getting an "runtime error '9' Subscript out of range" on ''Windows("FilenameExcel").Activate'' but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

How do I solve the problem?

```
Sub copyPastePPT()

Dim MyPPT As Object
Dim xChart As Excel.ChartObject
Set MyPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
Set myXLS = CreateObject("Excel.application")

FilenamePPT = OpenFileDialogPPT() 'Function to browse to a Power Point Presentation
FilenameExcel = OpenFileDialogXLS() 'Function to browse to a Excel Workbook

MyPPT.presentations.Open FilenamePPT
Workbooks.Open FilenameExcel


    Windows("FilenameExcel").Activate
    Sheets("Breakdown New").Select

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    'Copy chart to a specific slide

    Windows("FilenamePPT").Activate
    MyPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (3)
    MyPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Select
    MyPPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    MyPPT.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Sub copyPastePPT()

Dim MyPPT As Object, wb, pp
Dim xChart As Excel.ChartObject
Set MyPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
Set myXLS = CreateObject("Excel.application")

FilenamePPT = OpenFileDialogPPT() 'Function to browse to a Power Point Presentation
FilenameExcel = OpenFileDialogXLS() 'Function to browse to a Excel Workbook

Set pp = MyPPT.presentations.Open(FilenamePPT)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilenameExcel)

pp.Sheets("Breakdown New").ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy

'Copy chart to a specific slide

pp.Slides(3).Select
MyPPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
MyPPT.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method for this code

Comment: @Nikolas delete the answer you posted, as it is a comment. Then, are you running this code in Excel or Powerpoint? Also on what line are you getting the error.

Comment: I'm running this code in a excel workbook (not the same workbook I'm getting the graph to paste on a ppt)

Comment: Just one more question AAA ... Can I assign wb and pp without opening the file?

Comment: @Nikolas, no you have to open the file. You have to open a file to read/change its contents

Comment: I'm trying to avoid opening the file twice. If the file is already open can I just set without the .open or there is a other command to do this?

Comment: @Nikolas, are both files open? Which one is open? Because in your original code, that is how you opened them

Comment: Originally in my code I want to open a file which is not open. But the problem is: if pptx file is already open when I run my code, I get the same file open twice but the second one in read-only mode. (it doesn't happen with the xlsx file) and also the paste is done in the second file.

Comment: @Nikolas, if the pptx file is already open, you have to get the name of the file, and then you can use `Set pp = MyPPT.presentations.(FilenamePPT)` instead.